# Can't get scroll bar to appear on overflow

Tags: css, dynamic, web-applications, scrollbar, overflow

I'm building a MDI WEB application, and have a window created made by a `article` element, with a `header` and a `section` for content. Since it's an MDI app, the `article` is set to `absolute`, so it can overlap other windows. I need a scrollbar to appear in the content section, but not in the `header`.

```
<article id="win3">
    <header> … </header>
    <section> … </section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 500px;   
    width: 918px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: white;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 4px;
}
article>section {
    /* reduce diameter of rounded corner to match the inside curve of the border */
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It looks like the `overflow: auto` is ignored in Firefox (v 22), but the scrollbar does appear in Chrome.

Any ideas on how I make the scrollbar reliably when needed in the content section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key problem is with padding value, so you need to set width decreasing some percentage in your article>section

```
article>section {
    /* reduce diameter of rounded corner to match the inside curve of the border */
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    width: calc(100% - 30px) /* or set fixed width percentage like 90% */
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Calc is pretty cool - wasn't aware of that one. I got the scrollbar back in Chrome, but still no luck in Firefox.

Comment: for chrom use -webkit-calc(100% - 30px) and for firefox use -moz-calc() but note at least safari 6.0 works. So my suggestion use fixed width like 98%

Comment: Hmm, something not quite right. Even if I set a fixed size in pixels, it still doesn't get the scrollbar. When I inspect the page, Firefox draw a outline around the Section, and it clearly extends beyond the article. But Firefox still doesn't display the scrollbar.

Comment: Argh, I goofed. It's was the Min value that messed things up. It allowed the article the get smaller than than the min value allowed for.

Answer (score 0):

```
article {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 500px;   
    width: 918px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: white;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 4px;
    height:100px;
}
article>section {
    /* reduce diameter of rounded corner to match the inside curve of the border */
   overflow:auto;
   height:100%;
   border:none;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    min-height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It didn't solve the issue though. After making the suggested changes the Scrollbar no longer appear in Chrome, and it doesn't appear in Firefox either.