# horizontal scroll not working using datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a really big columns, around 40 columns and want to scroll horizontally, but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
            "oTableTools": {
                           "sScrollY": 200,
                           "sScrollX": "200%",
                           "sScrollXInner": "110%"
             }
    });
});
```

Comment: missing closing `});`

Comment: Sorry, posting mistake. Its not missing closing }); problem though.

Comment: this q/a might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049935/cant-get-scroll-bar-to-appear-on-overflow/18050108#18050108

Comment: seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/QS9pw/

Comment: I want horizontal scroll bar like in this example,  
http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html  
scroll bar is coming for like a whole page not for table only.

Comment: If that's what you want remove the otabletools section and move it to a child of the initializer like in the demo...ill make a jsfiddle tomorrow, please share your data if you want an exact solution...

Comment: Thanks @abc123, I somehow managed to run the code, partially using the demo file. Here's the complete file
http://pastebin.com/LuGDJR0h

Comment: congrats! let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You should post your own answer so this is resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178039/datatables-header-alignment-issue

Answer (score 6):

Removing the scroll-x-inner might help.

```
"sScrollXInner": "110%"
```

It worked for me.
Source
[datatables.net/forums](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/40892)

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is wrapping the target table with  tag by jquery and creating an break line 
 tag to separate please see below sample code

```
            $('#target_table').wrap("<div id='tableData' style='\n\
                                        overflow: auto;\n\
                                        overflow-y: hidden;\n\
                                        -ms-overflow-y: hidden\n\
                                        position:relative;\n\
                                        margin-right:5px;\n\
                                        padding-bottom: 15px;\n\
                                        display:block;\n\
                                   '>/");; 

           $("#tableData").before("<br/><br/>");
```

the problem is if your using sScrollX or scrollX is that not all datatables plugin version support this function and it depends also in jquery platform that we are using and not all browsers are supported like with the damn IE8,7 and 6.